# How to link old Twitter posts to new website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

I'm building a new website for a client and they have Twitter posts that link to there old website. The urls are formatted like so: website name/blog post title, however, the new url to those posts are as follows: website name/blogs/blog post title. As far as I know tweets can't be altered, so my question is how do I link these existing tweets to there corresponding blog posts that have the new blog path? How would this be handled? Deleting all the tweets would be very destructive, what is, if any, the way to handle this?

Comment: There are a lot, this is my first time handling something like this. How would I add a redirect?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how many there are - but the simplest answer would be "redirects". Put a redirect page at each of the old URLs forwarding the browser to the new URL.